# Output json to xls/csv from lambda to S3

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, aws-lambda

I am trying to convert JSON to excel/CSV and write it to S3

I have a Lambda(python) function. In this Lambda I'm parsing the JSON response of a boto method and extracting a specific set of values and I would like to write this as an excel into an s3 bucket.

```
for r in response_iterator:
    r_list.append(r)
r_dict=r_list[0]['EvaluationResults']
resouce_list=[]
for d in r_dict: resouce_list.append(d.get('EvaluationResultIdentifier').get('EvaluationResultQualifier'))
```

Below is the format of the extracted data, I would like to write this as a XLS/CSV into an S3 Bucket.

Sample:

```
[
  {
    "ResourceType": "AWS::XXXX::XXX",
    "ResourceId": "XXXX",
    "ConfigRuleName": "XXXX"
  },
  {
    "ResourceType": "AWS::XXXX::XXX",
    "ResourceId": "XXXX",
    "ConfigRuleName": "XXXX"
  },
  {
    "ResourceType": "AWS::XXXX::XXX",
    "ResourceId": "XXXX",
    "ConfigRuleName": "XXXX"
  }
]
```

How do I do this using AWS Lambda (Python)?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Are you experiencing an error? Please edit your question to provide more details. Also, would you consider writing a CSV file rather than an Excel file?

Comment: Added more details. xls is preferable but CSV should be okay if it's not possible. Thanks for the input. Cheers

Comment: To make a CSV, you can just loop through the list, printing each dict value separated by commas. You can then upload the resulting file to an Amazon S3 bucket. Have you tried any of this yet? Which particular part is causing you problems?